# How can I pass variable to a Twig view in this Codeigniter 3 application?

Tags: php, codeigniter, symfony, twig, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **[online newspaper/blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/twigPress/)** with **CodeIgniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4. I have decided to add themes to it. The application is **not HMVC**, only MVC.

The *themes* directory is outside *application* as can be see in the image below:

[image]

Inside *themes* I have the theme directory (of course) which contains the "master view", `layout.php`:

[image]

#### How I use the theme views

In `application/core` I have added a `MY_Loader.php` file with the following contents:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function theme_view($folder, $view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) {
      $this->_ci_view_paths = array_merge($this->_ci_view_paths, array(FCPATH . $folder . '/' => TRUE));
      return $this->_ci_load(array(
              '_ci_view' => $view,
              '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars),
              '_ci_return' => $return
          ));
    }

}
```

In my Posts controller's `index()` method, I load the view passing it the data:

```
public function index() {
   //more code here
   $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
   $this->load->theme_view('/themes/caminar/', 'layout', $data);
}
```

#### Using Twig for the themes

Even though I have no Symfony knowledge, I thought it was a good idea to use the *Twig* template engine to the theme(s).

For this purpose, I use **[CodeIgniter Simple and Secure Twig](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig)**. I have:

- Added the *Simple and Secure Twig* library:`application\libraries\Twig.php`;
- In the `third_party` directory I have added Twig itself.
- In `application\config\autoload.php` I have loaded twing:

  `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'form_validation', 'session', 'user_agent', 'twig');`
- Set the path for the Twig views in `application\libraries\Twig.php`:

`private $config = [ 'paths' => [FCPATH . '/themes', VIEWPATH], 'cache' => '/path/to/twig/cache', ];`

#### The problem

According to the docs of **[CodeIgniter Simple and Secure Twig](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig)**, we can set a global variable like so: `$this->twig->addGlobal('sitename', 'My Awesome Site');`

So, I added `$this->twig->addGlobal('siteTitle', 'My Awesome Site');` in the Posts controller:

```
public function index() {

  //call initialization method
  $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

  $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
  $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
  $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

    //use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
  $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);
  $this->twig->addGlobal('siteTitle', 'My Awesome Site');
  $this->load->theme_view('/themes/caminar/', 'layout', $data);
}
```

Yet, in `themes\caminar\layout.php` the line `<title>{{siteTitle}}</title>` does not display "My Awesome Site" inside the `<title>` tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using Twig, doesn't Twig have to render the view? Have you read the "Render" section? Even a read through the Twig.php Library file will explain a lot and what methods are available.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I followed the instructions  **[CodeIgniter Simple and Secure Twig](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig)**. Can you provide a link to the relevant (for my issue) Twig docs? Thanks!

Comment: Have you? Can you show in your code where you might have used something like $output = $this->twig->render('welcome', $data); (in the documentation you have read) to parse your Twig Template. You load Twig, Add a Global and that on it's own isn't going to do much. How are you expecting {{siteTitle}} to be parsed?

Comment: You already linked to it - but to be even more specific - try https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig#rendering-templates

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Replacing `/$this->load->theme_view('/themes/caminar/', 'layout', $data)` with `$this->twig->display('/themes/caminar/layout', $data)` results in this error being thrown: `Message: Class 'Twig_Environment' not found`.

Comment: Well of course! You've gone and put your themes outside of the default views folder ( you decided and chose to write a new method to override the default way) and twig is expecting your files to be in the views folder with an extension of .twig... It's very clearly stated in the docs that you keep referring too... So you really need to sit down and think about what it is you are doing and why. Simply changing commands without thinking about what it is you are doing is going to lead you down a long path of pain.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw That would be of great help for the project, which will be of great help for many people working in web development if it comes out as I intended. Don't miss the Bounty. Thanks!